# Interpolate between DateTimes in a List in a linear fashion and reapply those values to the list

Tags: c#

I have a class like this:

```
public class Datumsobjekt
{
    public string dateiname { get; set; }
    public DateTime zeit { get; set; }
}
```

When creating a `List<Datumsobjekt>` and filling it with values, I sometimes do not set `zeit`. `zeit` is always ascending, no sorting necessary.

Which leads to a(Example)

```
filename1.ext - 03.01.15
filename2.ext - 04.01.15
filename3.ext - 
filename4.ext - 08.01.15
```

How do I interpolate between dates in a linear fashion, so every `dateiname` has a `zeit` and reapply it to the list?

The goal should be something along the lines of

```
filename1.ext - 03.01.15
filename2.ext - 04.01.15
filename3.ext - 06.01.15
filename4.ext - 08.01.15
```

for the first example.

PS: It could also be

```
filename1.ext - 03.01.15
filename2.ext - 04.01.15
filename3.ext - 
filename4.ext - 
filename5.ext - 08.01.15
```

and

```
filename1.ext - 03.01.15
filename2.ext - 04.01.15
filename3.ext - 
filename4.ext - 
filename5.ext - 08.01.15
filename6.ext - 
filename7.ext - 
...
filenamen.ext - 
filenamen+1.ext - 09.01.15
```

ie arbitrary numbers of `dateiname` without a `zeit` and interrupted by given `zeit`.

Comment: Your question is not clear,  can you give some example scenario to help? Are you saying that initially in your list some items will not have a date time set, and then when you update the list, the list should set up/insert the date time so that it is inserted in a linear order and at the end each list item will have a datetime?

Comment: So what _should_ the `zeit` be for `filename3.ext`? `06.01.15`? And what should they be for `filename3.ext` and `filename4.ext` in your second example? Given you ignore the time part of the DateTime, is it acceptable for two successive records to hold the same date?

Comment: You need some mathematics calculations .

Comment: You forgot to mention which rules should be followed to fill the gaps. Is it just `[end hour] - [start hour] / [missing lines]`? You never increment the minutes. Is the value of the minutes something important or not? Some gaps cannot be filled with hours alone.

Comment: Start by explaining what the interpolated dates should be for your last example there, which has 2 groups of 2 elements missing their dates.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean but do you mean to fetch the elements in the list that don't have DateTime property set?  One way could be var filtered = list.Where(x => x.zeit == null).ToList();

Comment: You're missing an element in your last example, filename5 had the 8th, please take head when you construct examples.

Comment: @CodeCaster 06.01.15. BTW: this means 6th of january of 2015. In the mentioned example, it is two successive examples, but it could be much more successive `dateiname` without `zeit`. They should not have the same date, but increase in a linear fashion, ie each predecessor is earlier than it's successor.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen These are different examples to illustrate the point.

Comment: Why `filename3.ext - 06.01.15` and not `filename3.ext - 05.01.15`? Your question is really not clear. Try to provide example of _both_ the inputs and the expected output.

Comment: I gave an example

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed to even out the space between the last and first `dateiname` with a `zeit`.

Comment: @peeyushsingh Scenario: `dateiname` are actioncam-files, and `zeit` are Creation Time Stamps.

Comment: See if this is what you're looking for: https://gist.github.com/lassevk/af884497a394af29519ec0fc2bc610d0 - It is horribly inefficient for long arrays because of its recursive nature, I'll leave it as a (simple) excercise for you to fix.

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` has an operator [`Subtract`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.op_subtraction?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_op_Subtraction_System_DateTime_System_DateTime_) which gives a `TimeSpan` object as a result.

This can be used to subtract 2 `DateTime` objects;

```
System.DateTime date1 = new System.DateTime(1996, 6, 3, 22, 15, 0);
System.DateTime date2 = new System.DateTime(1996, 12, 6, 13, 2, 0);
System.DateTime date3 = new System.DateTime(1996, 10, 12, 8, 42, 0);

// diff1 gets 185 days, 14 hours, and 47 minutes.
System.TimeSpan diff1 = date2.Subtract(date1);

// diff2 gets 55 days 4 hours and 20 minutes.
System.TimeSpan diff2 = date2 - date3;
```

`TimeSpan` has a useful operator [`Division`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.op_division?view=netstandard-2.1&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.7.2) which takes a double as a divisor and gives a `TimeSpan` result.

A `TimeSpan` can be added to a `DateTime` to get a `DateTime` result.

---

If You need *n* values in-between two selected `DateTime`'s then the `TimeSpan` has to be divided by *n+1*.

Example 1:

```
dateTime1 = d1
datetime2 = ?    > 1 empty value
datetime3 = d3
```

So the *`interval = (datetime1 - datetime3) / (1 + 1)`*

And `datetime2 = datetime1 + interval`.

Example 2:

```
dateTime1 = d1
datetime2 = ?  \
datetime3 = ?   |
datetime4 = ?   |
datetime5 = ?   | 8 empty values
datetime6 = ?   |
datetime7 = ?   |
datetime8 = ?   |
datetime9 = ?  /
datetime10 = d10
```

So the *`interval = (datetime1 - dateime10) / (8 + 1)`*

And `datetime2 = datetime1 + interval`.

And `datetime3 = datetime2 + interval`.

And `datetime4 = datetime3 + interval`.

...

---

The funny thing with indexes of an array is that if 2 indexes are subtracted from each other then they give the required value:

For example 1:

```
index's: 3 - 1 = 2
```

For example 2:

```
index's: 10 - 1 = 9
```

---

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DateTime?[] dates = new DateTime?[]
        {
            new DateTime(2019,1,1),
            null,
            new DateTime(2019,1,3),
            null,null,
            new DateTime(2019,1,6),
            null,null,null,
            new DateTime(2019,1,10),
            null,null,null, null,null,null, null,null,null,
            new DateTime(2019,1,20),
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Before:");
        foreach (var zeit in dates)
            Console.WriteLine(zeit.HasValue ? zeit.ToString() : "<empty>");

        Interpolate_dates(dates);

        Console.WriteLine("\nAfter:");
        foreach (var zeit in dates)
            Console.WriteLine(zeit.HasValue ? zeit.ToString() : "!!ERROR!! - all dates should be interpolated.");
    }

    public static void Interpolate_dates(Span<DateTime?> dates)
    {
        if (dates.Length == 0)
            return;

        if (!dates[0].HasValue)
            throw new ArgumentException("First date cannot be null.");

        if (!dates[dates.Length - 1].HasValue)
            throw new ArgumentException("Last date value cannot be null");

        int last_filled_date_index = 0;

        for (int checking_index = 1; checking_index < dates.Length; checking_index++)
        {
            if (dates[checking_index].HasValue)
            {
                if (checking_index != last_filled_date_index + 1)
                {
                    Interpolate(dates, last_filled_date_index, checking_index);
                }

                last_filled_date_index = checking_index;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Interpolate(Span<DateTime?> dates, int earlier_date_idx, int later_date_idx)
    {
        TimeSpan interval = (dates[later_date_idx].Value - dates[earlier_date_idx].Value) / (later_date_idx - earlier_date_idx);

        for (int index = earlier_date_idx + 1; index < later_date_idx; index++)
        {
            dates[index] = dates[index - 1] + interval;
        }
    }
}
```